# How to mock only one method of one injected dependency and inject the rest normally?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, mockito

I'm writing tests for a project with a heavy use of dependency injection.

So normally I would just inject the object that I'm testing:

```
public class RegistrationTest
        extends WithApplication {

    private RegistrationController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Injector injector = app.injector();
        controller = injector.instanceOf(RegistrationController.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void openRegistrationView() {
        Result result = controller.registrationForm();
        assertEquals(OK, result.status());
    }
}
```

Now I need to mock a return value of a method of one of the dependencies of the class under test.

To do this I can use `@InjectMocks` and `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to inject mocked dependencies.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RegistrationTest
        extends WithApplication {

    @InjectMocks
    private RegistrationController controller;
    @Mock
    private FormFactory formFactory;
    @Mock
    private RegistrationIpCache registrationIpCache;

    @Test
    public void openRegistrationView() {
        doReturn("test").when(registrationIpCache).getLast();
        Result result = controller.registrationForm();
        assertEquals(OK, result.status());
    }
}
```

But while I only want to mock one method call of `RegistrationIpCache` I need to mock the whole class and also I need to mock all other dependencies of `RegistrationController` like `FormFactory` in my example. Now every method of all mocked classes doesn't work as expected.

Sure I can use `doCallRealMethod()` to mock every method of all dependencies

```
doCallRealMethod().when(formFactory).form(Registration.class);
```

But as you already can imagine the work and the amount of boilerplate code needed for this to work is extreme.

**Isn't it possible to inject my class normally and then only spy one dependency or mock one method of one dependency?**

Comment: No need of mocking all dependent methods just use @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) on private RegistrationIpCache registrationIpCache;

Comment: That is nice. I didn't know that. This helps with the uninitialized methods. The only boilerplate left are the '@Mock' declarations for dependencies I don't need to mock but still need because of '@InjectMocks'. Is there a similar Annotation parameter for '@InjectMocks' so that it automatically mocks every dependency that is not mocked in the test case?

Comment: there is no such annotation available and there is no mandatory rule that you have to mock all the dependent  objects of injected class. If you have usage of any dependent method then only mock else do not mock.

Comment: If I don't add a mock for every dependency, then the dependencies that are not explicitly mocked in the test case are null for the '@InjectMocks' class.

Comment: yes that is the behavior of InjectMocks in Mockito, if all your dependencies  are really used in actual class then you have to mock them else they will be set to null.

Comment: And there is no way around that? These dependencies are just boilerplate.

Comment: @InjectMocks(answer = Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS) give a try

Comment: Optional Answer to be used with Mockito.mock(Class, Answer) 

Answer can be used to define the return values of unstubbed invocations. 

This implementation can be helpful when working with legacy code. 

ReturnsMocks first tries to return ordinary return values (see ReturnsMoreEmptyValues) then it tries to return mocks. If the return type cannot be mocked (e.g. is final) then plain null is returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `@Spy` instead of a `@Mock`.

```
@InjectMocks
private RegistrationController controller;
@Mock
private FormFactory formFactory;
@Spy
private RegistrationIpCache registrationIpCache;
```

But be aware that in this case `@Spy` will try to use default constructor.
If the default constructor is not available use explicit constructor call:

```
@Spy
private RegistrationIpCache registrationIpCache = new RegistrationIpCache(dependencies);
```

Here is the cases when Mockito isn't able to instantiate your class from `@Spy` [javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.9.0/org/mockito/Spy.html):

> Mockito will try to find zero argument constructor (even private) and
>   create an instance for you. But Mockito cannot instantiate inner
>   classes, local classes, abstract classes and interfaces.

Here is the example of manually injecting dependencies:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RegistrationTest {
    private RegistrationController controller;

    private RegistrationIpCache spyRegistrationIpCache; //this is the dependencies that you need to spy

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        spyRegistrationIpCache = spy(realInstanceOfregistrationIpCache);

        controller = new RegistrationController(registrationIpCache, realInstanceOfFormFactory);
    }
}
```

In this case there is much more code that you have to write, but this give you much more control over the object instantiation and dependency injection.
Note that using constructor instantiation is not required. Since you do it manually you can instantiate it however you want.

Comment: Is there also a way to not have to mock every dependency in the test case (for example for formFactory in the above example)?

Comment: @Spen If you are using constructor dependency injection, the you can explicitly inject only needed dependency. In this case you have to use Mockito's methods `mock` and `spy` instead of annotations and create tested object manually.

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Do you have a link for me where I can read up on this or could you expand your answer on this?

Comment: @Spen I have extend the answer with the example. Hope that it will help you!

Comment: Thank you. Oh well, I think I misunderstood you. I thought you meant there is a way to instantiate 'RegistrationController' without the need to give all other dependencies (since they get injected automatically) and that I only need to add the dependency that I want to spy on. For example something like 'withDependency(registrationIpCacheSpy).mockInject(RegistrationController.class);'. I will go with your first answer and accept the boilerplate of defining all dependencies.